# displaying battery status in ionic 2 view

Tags: cordova, ionic2, battery

I am trying to display battery status in my ionic view. I got display network connection solution. but could not get to display battery status, I have installed ionic 2 battery status plugin

**HTML**

```
<h2>Battery status: {{status?.level}}</h2>
<h2>Battery is plugged:{{status?.isPlugged}}</h2>
```

**TypeScript**

```
status:any;
constructor(public alert:AlertController, public platform: Platform) { 
  this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
    let subscription = BatteryStatus.onChange().subscribe( (status) => { 
      console.log(status.level, status.isPlugged); 
      this.status=status.level;
    });
  });
}
```

You can clone from the below bitbucket git

```
$ git clone https://bitbucket.org/maniselvam/ionic2battery.git
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @AishApp i am not getting any error, nor am i getting battery status too

Comment: have you imported `import { BatteryStatus } from 'ionic-native';` ?

Comment: @gerdi yes i have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import the Battery Status on your TS file.

```
import { BatteryStatus } from 'ionic-native';
```

Declare a variable for battery status

```
Level:any = 0;
```

Initialise the plugin

```
let subscription = BatteryStatus.onChange().subscribe(
  (status) => {
    this.Level = status.level;
    console.log(status.level, status.isPlugged);
  }
);
```

**HTML**

```
<h1>Battery Level: {{Level}}</h1>
```